# Cant connect to salesforce using kettle spoon

Tags: salesforce, pentaho, kettle, salesforce-service-cloud, pentaho-cde

I'm trying to connect using kettle spoon installed in one of our db server but I'm getting the error below. I tried using the same .ktr file on my laptop and it is working fine..
I'm sure that the username and password are correct..

java.lang.Exception: 
Error connecting to Salesforce!
; nested exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect

```
at org.pentaho.di.ui.trans.steps.salesforceinput.SalesforceInputDialog.test(SalesforceInputDialog.java:1396)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.trans.steps.salesforceinput.SalesforceInputDialog.access$2000(SalesforceInputDialog.java:96)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.trans.steps.salesforceinput.SalesforceInputDialog$23.handleEvent(SalesforceInputDialog.java:1229)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.trans.steps.salesforceinput.SalesforceInputDialog.open(SalesforceInputDialog.java:1292)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.delegates.SpoonStepsDelegate.editStep(SpoonStepsDelegate.java:136)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.editStep(Spoon.java:7756)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.trans.TransGraph.editStep(TransGraph.java:2756)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.trans.TransGraph.mouseDoubleClick(TransGraph.java:705)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.readAndDispatch(Spoon.java:1183)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.start(Spoon.java:6968)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.main(Spoon.java:567)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.pentaho.commons.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:134)
```

Answer (score 1):

seems kettle is unable to reach the salesforce endpoint on the network.

try from the server where is kettle, open a console and try:

```
curl -i 'https://yourSalesforceWebservice.foo/services/Soap/u/21.0'
```

or

```
traceroute yourSalesforceWebservice.foo
```

(put the domain or the ip )